# graphicsmagick - tips for optimizing montage and composite?

Tags: graphicsmagick

for a little photo booth application have this problem:

I have 4 pictures, which i would like to tile together, using *montage*. The result get a 150px border using a transparent PNG and *composite*. But because the "frame" is larger than the base image, I have to add an additional *convert* to add artificial 150px border around the tiled image.

This is functional but very slow and seems not very elegant:

```
gm montage -geometry +20+20 -tile 2x2 /home/pi/dev/*.jpg miff:- | gm convert -border 150x150 miff:- miff:- | gm composite  /home/pi/dev/rahmen.png miff:- /home/pi/dev/partyknipse.JPG
```

Is there any way I could optimize this and speed up the process? Get rid of the *convert*?

I guess the -geometry parameter of the composite could be useful, but didn't fully understand it so far.

This is roughly what it should look like in the end:
[red border is a png, the four grey boxes are the tiled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDM1Q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how long your operations take, or what you expect, but here are a couple of ideas...

Assume I have `im1.jpg` through `m4.jpg` which are the 4 small images and a larger red frame that is a *"hollow"* PNG with a transparent hole in the middle.

Firstly, if you were to switch to ImageMagick (rather than GraphicsMagick) you could do it all in one go with:

```
convert frame.png -background white -flatten \
    im1.jpg -geometry +80+80   -composite    \
    im2.jpg -geometry +260+80  -composite    \
    im3.jpg -geometry +80+200  -composite    \
    im4.jpg -geometry +260+200 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Second, you could try something like this *batching* GraphicsMagick and storing intermediate steps in memory (MPR = Magick Program Register) which is effectively a named lump of RAM:

```
{ echo convert frame.png -background white -flatten mpr:frame; 
  echo montage -geometry +20+20 -tile 2x2 im*.jpg mpr:images; 
  echo composite mpr:images -geometry +100+40  mpr:frame result.png; } | gm batch -prompt off
```

[image]